# How can I get the "base url" of a Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I run my Phoenix app locally, the base URL for all requests is something like `http://localhost:4000`. In production, it's something like `https://example.com/`.

I want to pass this base URL along to my JavaScript. How can I get it?

Note:

- I don't want to check `conn`; this is something I want to set up during compilation or boot, not at request time.
- I know I can check `Application.get_env(:myapp, MyApp.Endpoint)[:url][:host] %`, but that doesn't include the scheme (`http` or `https`) or the port. If I have to piece this together from several places, I probably can, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Maybe this isn't simple because, as the generated comment in `dev.exs` says, "If desired, both `http:` and `https:` keys can be configured to run both http and https servers on different ports" ?

Comment: Phoenix itself builds URLs using the Endpoint config and Elixir's builtin `URI` module: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/10b6c1e8df915e82a4040f14f94afc1aed8ab47a/lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex#L235-L255.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`MyApp.Endpoint.url()`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.0-rc.3/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#c:url/0)

The link is to 1.3 docs since it documents all the functions generated in the app's `Endpoint` as callbacks, but the function is available at least since 1.2 (I haven't checked earlier).

Comment: Does this rely on your config files? e.g. do you need to setup some thing like this for it to work:   ```
config :example, Example.Endpoint,
    url: [host: "example.com", port: 80, scheme: "https"]
```

Comment: This works but if the app is running behind some reverse proxy e.g. Nginx or HAProxy it can be problematic. Guess the only way under such situations is to manually add a variable in application config to document the "real" URL then? Or use a system environment variable for that.

Answer (score 2):

## Use a path helper

Whoops, there's an obvious solution for this. :)

```
MyApp.Router.Helpers.page_url(MyApp.Endpoint, :index)
```

It feels a little awkward to use a specific named route for this, but it works. I'm open to a more semantic solution, though.

Comment: Note that in the newest Phoenix it would be `MyAppWeb` instead of `MyApp`.